# NSYearCalendarUnit deprecated in iOS

Tags: ios, warnings, deprecated

I'm using `NSYearCalendarUnit` `NSMonthCalendarUnit` `NSDayCalendarUnit` but unfortunately, these  "Calendar Units" are reported as deprecated first in `IOS 8.0`.
What's the alternative of them, or how do I avoid these warnings.

```
unsigned unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit;
```

Comment: So you mean deprecated no?

Comment: I don't code in Obj-C but I am sure if something is deprecated you have to switch to the new version of that piece of code/module/function/whatever

Comment: @JuanRocamonde Yeah I'm finding the newer version dear.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use `NSCalendarUnitYear`:

```
NSCalendarUnit unitFlags = NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth |  NSCalendarUnitDay;
```

---

I infer from the code sample in the original question that you were looking for Objective-C answer, but for those looking for Swift equivalent, you would do:

```
let unitFlags: NSCalendarUnit = [.Year, .Month, .Day]
```

---

Note, in Swift 3, the equivalent would be:

```
let unitFlags: Set<Calendar.Component> = [.year, .month, .day]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is correct one:

```
let flags: NSCalendarUnit = .CalendarUnitYear | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitDay
```